# Get CSV of specific data from NOAA NAM-NMM Dataset using wgrib2

Tags: weather, noaa

I am trying to get data from the [NAM-NMM Dataset](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pygrib) and am having a lot of trouble getting the data I want out of the grb2 files. How can I get a CSV file containing information like Probability of precipitation, Probability of freezing precipitation, TMAX, TMIN, etc... plus time of forecast for all latitudes and longitudes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [wgrib2](http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/wesley/wgrib2/). This has a command line switch to get output as csv file. This should be simple like this:-

```
wgrib2 -match "TMAX" -match "800 mb" /path/to/file.grib2 -csv name.csv
```

Comment: This is what I ended up using